# Помогите, пожалуста, решил изучить ретрофит - выдается такая ошибка

Tags: java

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.translate, PID: 11284
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1448)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:344)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:327)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
        at retrofit.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:116)
        at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at com.example.translate.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Process 11284 terminated.
```

Comment: используйте enqueue() вместо execute()

Comment: Response<Object> response = call.enqueue(a eto kak pustim ostavit ?);

Answer (score 1):

В Android приложениях нельзя отправлять запросы/разрешать доменное имя/делать любые Network-операции в основном потоке. Делайте http запросы в отдельном потоке.

Comment: mainActivity private final String URL="https://translate.yandex.ru";

Comment: @POST("/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate")  это в